# where does this param symbol come from in Rails session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm reading Rails 3 Way by Obie Fernandez. He's demonstrating the use of a plugin Authlogic, and created a User and  UserSession model and a UsersController and UserSessionsController.

He hasn't created any views (but he might assume some exist)

In the UserSessionsController, he creates this code

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController 

     def new
        @user_session = UserSession.new
     end

    def create
     @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session]) 
       if @user_session.save
       redirect_to user_path(current_user) 
    else
        render :action => :new 
       end
    end

    def destroy 
      current_user_session.destroy 
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end 

    end
```

My question relates to the create method. When he writes

```
UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
```

where is  `:user_session` coming from? I undersdtand that UserSession.new instantiates a new object, but where do the params come from? and what names would they have?

Does it depend on something in the imaginary view? or are these params automatically generated by Rails based on the name of the Models?

Answer (score 2):

`params` is a special hash that is passed to all actions, regardless of the type. If a given action has no parameters, then it's simply empty. It's how you can pass parameters from a page/form/URL parameters into the action. One of the most common sources of parameters are data elements from a form.

In the case of authlogic, it contains user credentials for creating the user session (username, password).

Check out [the parameters section](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html) for more information.

Comment: I'm not asking what params is, but rather what :user_session param is? would that only have come from a form? who or what created the specific :user_session param?

Comment: The login form has a name attribute of `user_session`, or otherwise wraps the UserSession model, yes? The name is automatically generated by the model that is wrapped in the form you're filling out/the "name" attributed on the generated form. In the parameters section of the link I provided, they show an input element, with a name attribute of 'post[name]`. In the receiving action, you'll have the value in that field available in the hash in `params[:post][:name]`

Comment: Basically, I'm saying, take a look at the view code, and specifically the login form, then look at the actual HTML source that Rails is generating for that page, and compare the two. I think it will be clearer where the naming convention comes from, and how it passes through. By following standard naming conventions, Rails will take care of many of connecting attribute names, etc. for you so everything works together.